# Error : The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, linq, entity-framework

I am using EF4 within Data Entities project and there is another project with Business entities.

I am using the explicit operator for casting the Data entities objects to Business object, the first class is Order and second is SalesChannel

```
[DataContract]
public class Order
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid OrderID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public SalesChannel SalesChannel { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator Order(Data.Entities.Order orderEntity)
    {
        return new Order()
        {
            OrderID = orderEntity.OrderID,
            SalesChannel = **(SalesChannel)orderEntity.SalesChannel**
        };
}
```

and

```
[DataContract]
public class SalesChannel
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid SalesChannelID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator SalesChannel(Data.Entities.SalesChannel salesChannelEntity)
    {
        return new SalesChannel()
        {
            SalesChannelID = salesChannelEntity.SalesChannelID,
            Name = salesChannelEntity.Name,
            Email = salesChannelEntity.Email,
            Description = salesChannelEntity.Description
        };
    }
}
```

However, while casting the SalesChannel object I am getting this error:

`The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.`

I think the casting is not don properly at SalesChannel class.

```
using (var orderDataProvider = new OrderDataProvider())
{
    var orderList = orderDataProvider.GetAllOrders();
    orders.AddRange(orderList.Select(order => (Order) order));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is deferred execution. Change the inner statement, that's performing the `AddRange`, to output a `List<T>` and that will force the query to execute. I had this same problem in some code not that long ago.

```
orderList.Select(order => (Order) order).ToList();
```

You're doing well by wrapping it in a `using`. However, because you're being prudent you're also seeing the effects of deferred execution.

### UPDATE

Based on the fact that the issue is actually with getting the `SalesChannel`, make sure to issue the `Include` on that type so that it gets loaded immediately rather than lazy loaded.

Comment: I have also used the ToList(), but the problem is while casting the SalesChannel = (SalesChannel)orderEntity.SalesChannel

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what should I Include on the that Type?

Comment: All the Order properties are casted properly, However SalesChannel is complex type in the Order, while casting SalesChannel from that of SalesChannel Entity object, there is going something wrong

Comment: @MilindChavan, I'm referring to the [`Include` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) on the `ObjectQuery`.